# Messages disappearing on clicking notifications

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have created a SMS receiver app on android studio but when I click the notification all the previous messages are disappeared. I have used shared preferences for storing the messages in mobile.

Notification Manager

```
public static void showNotification(Context context, String contact, String message) {
        createNotificationChannel(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MsgActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.person)
                .setContentTitle(contact)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

On message activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.msg_activity);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        contact = intent.getStringExtra("MOBILE_NUM");
        MainActivity.loadArray(this, MainActivity.contactAndMsgList,"msg_size", "msg_");
        for (int i = (MainActivity.contactAndMsgList.indexOf(contact) + 1); i < MainActivity.contactAndMsgList.size(); i++) {
            if (MainActivity.contactList.contains(MainActivity.contactAndMsgList.get(i))) {
                break;
            }
            messages.add(MainActivity.contactAndMsgList.get(i));
        }
        recyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        RecyclerViewAdapterMsg msgAdaptor = new RecyclerViewAdapterMsg(messages);
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(msgAdaptor);
    }
```

I have called the showNotification in SMS receiver class after receiving the message and phone number.

`NotificationUtils.showNotification(context, phoneNo.toString(), msg.toString());`